# Limit at non continuous point or arctangent

Tags: real-analysis, limits, trigonometry

For an integral I need to calculate, I need to calculate the following limit:

$$\lim_{t \rightarrow \pi^-} \arctan \left(\frac{\tan(\frac{t}{2})}{3}\right).$$
I have used the formula:

$$\tan(\frac{t}{2})= \frac{\sin(t)}{\cos(t)-1}$$
and then applied L'Hopital's rule to show that the limit inside of the arctangent is $\infty$ but, although I know $\tan(\frac{\pi}{2})$ is also $\infty$, I need to justify that the limit is $\frac{\pi}{2}$ rigorously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative we can use that for $\theta>0$

$$\arctan \theta = \frac \pi 2 -\arctan\left(\frac 1 \theta\right)$$

that is

$$ \arctan \left(\frac{\tan(\frac{t}{2})}{3}\right) = \frac\pi 2 - \arctan \left(\frac{3}{\tan(\frac{t}{2})}\right) \to \frac \pi 2-\arctan 0=\frac \pi 2$$

Answer (score 0):

There is no undeterminate form here :
$$\lim_{t \rightarrow \pi^-} \tan \left( \frac{t}{2}\right) = +\infty$$

so $$\lim_{t \rightarrow \pi^-} \frac{1}{3}\tan \left( \frac{t}{2}\right) = +\infty$$

so $$\lim_{t \rightarrow \pi^-} \arctan\left(\frac{1}{3}\tan \left( \frac{t}{2}\right) \right) = \lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty} \arctan\left(x\right) = \frac{\pi}{2}.$$